# Which model does this equation come from in fixed bias circuit?

Tags: bjt, biasing

In fixed bias circuit
[image]

I calculated voltage gain by this :

> I measured the DC response in simulation as:

> Ic  = 3.73 mA
> Ib  = 15.7 uA
> Vc  = 11.3 mV
> Vbe = 824  mV
> I calculated re (ac emitter resistance)

> re  = 25mV/Ic
> = 25mV/3.73 mA
> = 6.67 ohm
> I calculated voltage gain from

> A  =  (R1//R3)/re
> =  4761/6.67
> = 713

Which Multisim voltage gain is not match my calculation.
And I asked question about this and found answer that  :

"For a fixed bias amplifier like this the correct (and overkill formula) should be

> Av=−α∗(RC//RLoad//RB)/re

where

> re=Vth/Ie=kT/(qIe)
> α=0.996 "

Which model did they use in second voltage gain?
And where does this equation from?

Comment: What is the emitter connected to?

Comment: @qrk Sorry , emitter connected to ground.

Comment: The answer you have "found" is wrong. Such a base resistor RB (in your drawing R1) has no influenbce on the gain. I

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned gain formula  A=-(Rc||RL)/re=-gm*(Rc||RL) is a rough expression only. It neglects the finite output resistance rce of the transistor (not an ideal current source) as well as some other non-dealities which are covered in the Ebers-Moll equations (core of the BJT models used in the simulators).

See here:
[Measuring BJT (Ebers-Moll) parameters](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/202302/measuring-bjt-ebers-moll-parameters)